# how to see a change in a value in looping?

Tags: vb.net, loops, modulo

how to see a change in a value in the following looping

```
Dim one, two, three, four, five as integer;

two = 0;
three = 0;
four = 0;
five = 0;

for one = 0 to 10 
  if ((one Mod 4) = 0) Then
     two = two + (one+three)-five
  End if
  if ((one Mod 3) = 0) Then
     three = three + (one+two)-four
  End if
  if ((one Mod 2) = 0) Then
     four = four + (one+two)-three
  End if
  if ((one Mod 1) = 0) Then
     five = one+ two + three
  End if
  Next
```

- two = how much has it changed?
- How much is the value of one when the two value changes?

Comment: Either log the values you want to see in the places you want to see them, or add variables to your watch collection in the debug windows and watch them change as you step through your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "see"? Please be specific because that could mean different things to different people. For instance, are you saying that you want the application user to be able to see those values as your loop executes or that you want to see those values yourself, as the developer, as you step through the code. Just avoid vague language in the first place and then we can avoid confusion and this sort of back and forth to find out what you actually mean.

Comment: what is the final value of variable one,two..... five?

Comment: Firstly, why are you asking us that when you have the code right in front of you and can run it for yourself? Secondly, what has the final value got to do with seeing the values as the loop executes? Thirdly, why are you asking additional questions in the comments?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a homework assignment where the purpose is **NOT** to see if you can produce the right answer. Rather, the purpose of this assignment is to teach you to use the Visual Studio debugger.

Therefore, the correct answer here is to create a new VB.Net Console project in Visual Studio. Then paste this code into the Main method for the new project, set a breakpoint (`F9`) on the first line and hit `F5` to start the debugger.

When you reach the breakpoint, you can use the Locals window at the bottom of Visual Studio to check the value of each local variable, and use the `F10` key to continue running just one line of code at a time.

In this way, you will be able to see when a variable changes, as well as the value of other variables at that time, and in this way answer the questions.